# How to find those transformations on $x$ and $y$ for which the given functions coincide?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, linear-transformations

I have these two-variables functions for $x,y\in(0,2\pi)$.
$$f(x,y)=-5+4 \cos (x-y)+11 \cos (2 x-2 y)+19 \cos (x-3 y)\\+13 \cos (2 x-4 y)+7 \cos (2 x)-3 \cos (2 y)  $$
$$  g(x,y)= -5-4 \cos (x-y)+11 \cos (2 x-2 y)+19 \cos (x-3 y)\\-13 \cos (2 x-4 y)-7 \cos (2 x)+3 \cos (2 y)   $$

Plotting both functions, I see that they may transform to each other under particular transformations of $x$ and $y$; how can I find those transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use $\cos(x\pm\pi) = -\cos(x)$.

Since you want $7\cos(2x)$ to transform into $-7\cos(2x)$, this suggest the change $x \to x\pm \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. Similarly, to get $3\cos(2y)$ from $-3\cos(2y)$ we change $y \to y\pm\tfrac{\pi}{2}$. This leaves four sign combinations to try.

We have $$f(x+\tfrac{\pi}{2},y-\tfrac{\pi}{2}) = g(x,y)$$